# Is UV unwrapping broken in Blender 3.6?

Tags: modeling, uv

**.blend file:**
[image]

UV islands are stretched differently no matter what i do.
I can use "Smart UV Project" and get the correct result:
[image: Smart UV Project]

Then i use "Seams from Islands" and "Unwrap" again, and it is broken again:

[image: Unwrap after Smart UV Project]

What can i do about it?

Comment: Have you applied the scale of your object in Object mode?

Comment: @moonboots Yes, i have

Comment: Please share your file via blend-exchange.com adding the link on that page to your question so that we can see what's happening.

Comment: @JohnEason Done, please check it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've pinned some vertices in the *UV Editor*, when you'll unwrap again the islands will keep the same shape, just unpin with <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> and unwrap again.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i didn't even think about it